# Averaging column values of a matrix in R

Tags: r

I have a matrix of 7000 rows x 160 columns, i want to take the average of 20 values in each row to make it 1 value i.e. column avg(1:20) = 1st new value, avg(21:40) = 2nd new value ..... avg(141:160) 8th and  last new value for row 1, will do the same foe all rows, at the end my matrix will be 7000 x 8 ie. 160/20 = 8. what is the fastest way to archive this in R?

eg. at the end

```
1st    2 4 5 6 7 7 9 4
2nd    3 6 5 3 6 7 4 3 
       ...............

7000th 5 6 7 4 5 6 7 6
```

i tried this, it works but too slow!

```
res <- matrix(T, nrow = 7000, ncol = 8)

for (i in 1:nrow(m)){
  s <- 0
  k <- 1
  for (j in 1:ncol(m)){ 
    s <- s + m[i,j]
    if(j %% 20 == 0){
      a <- s/20
      res[i,k] <- a
      k <- k + 1
      s <- 0
    }

  }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: allocate a results matrix; loop over `(i in 1:8)`; compute `j <- (i-1)*20+1; result[,i] <- rowSums(m[,(j:j+19)])` ?

Comment: Wouldn't this be an answer @Ben?

Comment: I guess. I was in a hurry.  Anyone is welcome to post that as an answer if I don't get around to it first.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
# example - you have this already
set.seed(1)    # for reproducible example
M <- matrix(rnorm(7000*160),nc=160)

# you start here...
indx   <- rep(1:8,each=20)
result <- sapply(1:8,function(i)rowMeans(M[,which(indx==i)]))
head(result)
#            [,1]        [,2]         [,3]        [,4]        [,5]        [,6]         [,7]        [,8]
# [1,]  0.2127915 -0.38038950 -0.087656347  0.05933375 -0.23819112  0.03943897 -0.008970226  0.03841767
# [2,]  0.3548025  0.31491967  0.144773998 -0.05972595 -0.17191220  0.04243383  0.047314127 -0.16848104
# [3,] -0.2559990  0.35942642  0.003344486  0.23424747  0.09022379  0.58685507 -0.157652263 -0.25611335
# [4,]  0.3723693  0.23901787 -0.304657019  0.41620451  0.26005406  0.09726225 -0.434833656  0.07112657
# [5,]  0.4457805  0.08682639  0.048011727  0.15753612  0.30271061 -0.05484104 -0.103921787 -0.12066903
# [6,] -0.2823111 -0.00243217  0.055399402  0.31365508  0.17940294  0.26896135 -0.439110424 -0.30403590
```

Comment: Thanks, just the optimization i needed...worked like a charm! @ jihoward

Comment: mine worked but too slow...will be using sapply and co. for such loops

Answer (score 0):

Another way using `rowsum` and jlhoward's data ("M"):

```
n = 20
ans = t(rowsum(t(M), rep(seq_len(ncol(M) / n), each = n))) / n
head(ans)
```